# NGINX - настройка location

Tags: django, apache, nginx, location

Плавно перевожу сайт с Apache на Django, фронтует NGINX
То есть когда определенные страницы готовы я добавляю правило в location.
Но уже правил стало слишком много, и если внутри вносятся изменения их надо дублировать.

Решил попробовать такую конструкцию через переменную, то есть если переменная установлена - редиректим на одно, если нет то на другой:

```
    #1123
    set $django "yes";
    #set $django "no";
        if ( $request_uri = "/new_page.html") {  set $django "yes"; }
        if ( $django = "yes" ) {
                proxy_pass  http://unix:/run/django.sock;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                break;
        }
    #321
location / {
                proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

в итоге правило не срабатает. куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
upstream backend_old {
   server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

upstream backend_new {
   server unix:/run/django.sock;
}

map $uri  $backend {
    ~/new_page.html         backend_new;
    ^/second_page.html$     backend_new;
    /other_page.html$       backend_new;
    default                 backend_old;
}

server {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://$backend;
    }
}
```

---

`upstream`: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

`map`: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

*If is Evil...*: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: `^/new_page.html$     backend_new;`
надо заменить на
`~/new_page.html     backend_new;`

и тогда заработает.

Comment: ну, я из головы писал и на основании ненастоящих данных. `~/new_page.html` - твой частный случай ))

Comment: отредактировал ответ. поставь галку "принято", если он тебе помог

Comment: да спасибо большое, работает